# managed metadata service error

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-metadata, term-store

I've installed a sharepoint server 2010 with a trial key.
When i go to the term store, i get this error:

The Managed Metadata Service or Connection is currently not available. The Application Pool or Managed Metadata Web Service may not have been started. Please Contact your Administrator.

I googled a lot and try the 5 solutions here without success.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/guruketepalli/archive/2013/08/09/sharepoint-error-the-managed-metadata-service-or-connection-is-currently-not-available-the-application-pool-or-managed-metadata-web-service-may-not-have-been-started-please-contact-your-administrator.aspx

i've no more idea to make it works.

Thanks

Comment: could you please check and make sure, MMS proxy associated with the Central Admin services association.

Comment: also make sure the Application pool of your Web Application having the permission on the MMS. step # 2